# Regarding Akka message transfer performance: many small messages or less large messages?

Tags: performance, networking, akka, message-passing

For a data-mining algorithm I am currently developing using Akka, I was wondering if Akka implements performance optimizations of the messages that are sent.

For instance, if I have an Actor that emits a very large number of messages to the same other Actor, is it good to encapsulate a set of messages into another large message? Or does Akka have some sort of buffer itself so that not one message but many messages are transfered over the network at once?

I am asking this question because the algorithm is supposed to be executed remotely on a cluster where transfer performance is important and I currently have no option to just do benchmarks myself.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, so I could be wrong here, but with Akka Remoting, when you send a message to a remote actor via `!` or `?`, that message will be transmitted almost immediately.  If you want to do anything around batching and sending only after a set batch size or amount of time (whichever happens first), then I think you're going to have to roll this yourself.  I'd be interested to see if I'm wrong here as I need this same functionality and planned on rolling it myself.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll implement batching and will try it as soon as I have access to a cluster. I will post my result here.

Comment: Akka messages have some overhead (for example target actor path), so it might make sense to send larger messages. But I think "larger" is more like in the few kBytes range. I would probably avoid sending enormous messages though, since they delay all possible other messages while it gets through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For messages passed in Akka on the same machine, I don't think it matters a lot whether you use small message or an aggregation of messages as single message. The additional overhead of many calls versus having to loop while processing the aggregation is minimal I think.
I would prefer using small messages because it keeps the system simpler.

However, when sending messages over the network Akka is using HTTP and so there is the additional HTTP overhead costs for setting up a connection etc. Therefore you might choose here to aggregate some messages into a single message.
However, this also depends on your use case. Buffering implies waiting for more until there are enough (or a timeout occured). If you cannot wait, e.g. because you need fast responses, then you still need to send each message over individually.

I don't think there is a standard Akka actor available which does some aggregation of messages. Maybe a special kind of routing could be applied which does the buffering.

Or you might have a look at Akka Streams. That does support buffering of messages.